# One-to-many recursive relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

The class:

```cs
public class User 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? CreatBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

The model builder:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Users>(entity =>
    {
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        entity.Property(e => e.Name);
        entity.HasOne(d => d.Creator)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreatedBy);
    });
```

Usage:

```cs
db.Users.Include(c => c.Creator)
    .Where(u => u.Id == id)
    .Take(1);
```

The result:

```
{id: "fac41303-21c9-4424-9424-a579b52c0afb", Name: "user"}
creator: {id: "9655344b-e6df-4dfa-8091-d879806a389f", Name: "Creator1"}
creator: {id: "78d7b863-8fd7-4918-808a-cb61ec5cd504", Name: "Creator2"}
creator: {id: "3dc192e8-11e9-412f-ac38-38d118eb16db", Name: "Creator3"}
```

I created a one-to-many recursive self-referencing relationship,
and I wonder if there is a way to get only the first child, with this example only one creator, I don't want to get the creator of the creator, only the first creator.
With the code I have now I am geting the child of the child and so on.....

Comment: Add `AsNoTracking()` to the query and EF will not fixup navigation properties.